# How to use current FactoryGirl factory as attribute on an association?

Tags: ruby, factory-bot

Here's what I've got:

```
factory :application do
  association :gs_collector
end

factory :zephyr do
  quantity 1
  association :application, gs_collector: nil

  after(:create) do |instance|
    instance.application.update(zephyr: instance)
  end
end
```

This works, but seems awkward.  In the Zephyr factory, I'd rather set the zephyr property of the application association to the current factory.  That way, I wouldn't have to use the after(:create) callback. Something like:

```
factory :zephyr do
  quantity 1    
  association :application, gs_collector: nil, zephyr: self
end
```

But that doesn't work - using self throws an error. How can I do this?